# How to use a 'Searched Case Expression' in the .select method of a datatable? (ASP/ADO.net)

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, select, ado.net, case

Can someone please show me how to use a [**Searched** CASE expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) inside of the [select method of a datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)? I keep getting the error:

> Syntax error: Missing operand after 'WHEN' operator

This is what I'm trying and it's not working with the error above.

```
DataRow[] unMappedRows = matches.Select("(CASE WHEN TRUE THEN 1 END) = 1");
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. the Searched CASE expression you are trying is not a filter...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

According to that, and together with the link you provided you are trying something like this (in t-sql pseudo code)

```
select *
from  table
where (case when true then 1 end) = 1
```

which isn't allowed.

Hope it helps

Comment: Mark - thanks for your answer. However, I don't see where in the linked documentation it says you can't use a case expression in the filter syntax. The param is referred to as a `filterExpression` and under remarks it says "To create the filterExpression argument, use the same rules that apply to the DataColumn class's Expression property value for creating filters". In there, it's just referred to as an expression without any exclusion of Case expressions.

Comment: Mark - if your answer is correct, would it be possible to use any Case expression within the .select method then? If so, could you provide a simple example?

Comment: Mark - after some more searching, I think you're right about CASE expressions not being supported in .select method despite the docs not explicitly defining that.